# Why are results changing as soon as I use Apache POI in my code?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have narrowed my problem down to this line in my code :
"Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();"
As soon as I comment out this line and print the results directly using System.out statement, all results are fine.

I have even tried to use XSSFWorkbook, the problem persits.
Then I thought my external library is a problem and DOUBLE is what is causing problem. I tried changing the inner HashMap value type to Double (from Java), still doesn't work.

Edit: I also tried removing the code not shown here and running just the code I have shown here. The problem persists.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
HashMap<SET<Integer>, HashMap<String,DOUBLE>> Qvalues= 
bb.MSQATVHM();
Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
for(SET<Integer> IntegerSet:Qvalues.keySet()){
    System.out.println(IntegerSet);
    System.out.println(Qvalues.get(IntegerSet));
    }
// Program continues.....the rest doesn't matter here.
}
```

Expected: [1733]

{Value1=0.0657304324073498, Value2=21213.0, Value3=18.57715885746071, Value4=0.33081495617910694}

Actual: [1733]

{Value1=0.0394381995860269, Value2=12727.800000000001, Value3=11.14629515620783, Value4=0.35655228866335265}

Comment: Where does `SET` and `DOUBLE` come from? They're not normal Java, that might also be where the issue is. Are you sure adding the `Workbook` *without* changing other code results in this consistenly?

Comment: @Mark They are from external Library and I have tried getting rid of them, the problem persists.
I didn't understand your question. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Also [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) "makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.", it seems like you're expecting that it's consistent.

Comment: @Mark: I didn't understand your question. Can you please elaborate? I agree that the #HashMap is not consistent but the values in the actual result are values which are not even there in the #HashMap read. I am not concerned about the order they appear.

Comment: I guess then the issue is that `bb.MSQATVHM();` returns incorrect results, right?

Comment: @Mark: As I said, as soon as I comment out the WorkBook line, bb.MSQATVHM(); produces the expected result. I have been scratching my brains over it since yesterday. I have also tried another java class with just the code I have shown here (removing all other code).

Comment: The only thing `Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();` does is instantiating a `HSSFWorkbook` object in random access memory. If that leads to such inconsistency then `SET` might be inconsistently stored in RAM? As we don't know what `SET` actually is, we cannot know. Also thread issues, you are conceal, might be the reason. Neither `HasMap` nor `HSSFWorkbook` are thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

Only to show that your assumption is wrong:

Complete Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

import java.util.*;

public class UsingPOITest  {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  HashMap<Set<Integer>, HashMap<String, Double>> Qvalues = new HashMap<Set<Integer>, HashMap<String, Double>>();
  Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
  set.add(new Integer(1733));
  HashMap<String, Double> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Double>();
  hashMap.put("Value1", new Double(0.0657304324073498));
  hashMap.put("Value2", new Double(21213.0));
  hashMap.put("Value3", new Double(18.57715885746071));
  hashMap.put("Value4", new Double(0.33081495617910694));
  Qvalues.put(set, hashMap);
  Workbook workbook = null;
  //workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
  System.out.println("Workbook: " + workbook);
  for(Set<Integer> IntegerSet : Qvalues.keySet()){
   System.out.println(IntegerSet);
   System.out.println(Qvalues.get(IntegerSet));
  }
 }
}
```

Result without creating the `HSSFWorkbook`:

```
axel@arichter:~/Dokumente/JAVA/poi/poi-4.0.1$ java -cp .:./*:./lib/*:./ooxml-lib/* UsingPOITest 
Workbook: null
[1733]
{Value3=18.57715885746071, Value4=0.33081495617910694, Value1=0.0657304324073498, Value2=21213.0}
```

Result with creating the `HSSFWorkbook`:

```
axel@arichter:~/Dokumente/JAVA/poi/poi-4.0.1$ java -cp .:./*:./lib/*:./ooxml-lib/* UsingPOITest 
Workbook: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook@573fd745
[1733]
{Value3=18.57715885746071, Value4=0.33081495617910694, Value1=0.0657304324073498, Value2=21213.0}
```

---

I can reproducing the problem if `bb`, what returns the `HashMap<Set<Integer>, HashMap<String, Double>> Qvalues`, runs in a separate thread and this is continously updating the `MSQATVHM`. Then the creating the workbook is only the issue because it needs some time in which the `MSQATVHM` is updated again.

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

import java.util.*;

public class UsingPOITest  {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  BB bb = new BB();
  bb.start();
  Thread.sleep(1000);

  HashMap<Set<Integer>, HashMap<String, Double>> Qvalues = bb.MSQATVHM();
  System.out.println(Qvalues);

  Thread.sleep(1000);

  for(Set<Integer> IntegerSet : Qvalues.keySet()){
   System.out.println(IntegerSet);
   System.out.println(Qvalues.get(IntegerSet));
  }
 }

 static class BB extends Thread {

  HashMap<Set<Integer>, HashMap<String, Double>> msQatVHM = new HashMap<Set<Integer>, HashMap<String, Double>>();

  void setMSQatVHM(int atVHM) {
   msQatVHM.clear();
   Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
   set.add(new Integer(1733));
   HashMap<String, Double> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Double>();
   if (atVHM == 0) { 
    hashMap.put("Value1", new Double(0.0657304324073498));
    hashMap.put("Value2", new Double(21213.0));
    hashMap.put("Value3", new Double(18.57715885746071));
    hashMap.put("Value4", new Double(0.33081495617910694));
   } else {
    hashMap.put("Value1", new Double(0.0394381995860269));
    hashMap.put("Value2", new Double(12727.800000000001));
    hashMap.put("Value3", new Double(11.14629515620783));
    hashMap.put("Value4", new Double(0.35655228866335265));
   }
   msQatVHM.put(set, hashMap);
  }

  HashMap<Set<Integer>, HashMap<String,Double>> MSQATVHM() {
   return msQatVHM;
  }

  public void run() {
   setMSQatVHM(0);
   try {
    this.sleep(1000);
   } catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
   }
   setMSQatVHM(1);
  }
 }

}
```

Result:

```
axel@arichter:~/Dokumente/JAVA/poi/poi-4.0.1$ javac -Xlint:deprecation -Xlint:unchecked -cp .:./*:./lib/*:./ooxml-lib/* UsingPOITest.java 
axel@arichter:~/Dokumente/JAVA/poi/poi-4.0.1$ java -cp .:./*:./lib/*:./ooxml-lib/* UsingPOITest
{[1733]={Value3=18.57715885746071, Value4=0.33081495617910694, Value1=0.0657304324073498, Value2=21213.0}}
[1733]
{Value3=11.14629515620783, Value4=0.35655228866335265, Value1=0.0394381995860269, Value2=12727.800000000001}
```

---

Disclaimer:
The code above is meant to show problems and, as all my code samples here, it is **not** meant to be ready for productive usage.

The last code part shows misusing of multi-threading. `HashMap` is not thread safe and so it even can be that single items in that map are not ready when the other thread tries getting them.

Also the variable names from code in the question partially are taken over in my code allthogh they are violating the `Java` naming conventions. This is done because of comparability. I know that variables should not be named `Qvalues` but `qValues` - `camleCaseStyle` starting lower case. And a method never should be named `MSQATVHM` as capitalized names should be names of constants only.

Comment: Hi Axel, thank you. I was trying the same after your comment and I know what you mean now. I have the same solution. I am now trying to see if this works on my main code too.

Comment: Nope, I tried to convert my SET to string because that was easier to do a quick check. DOUBLE I already converted to Double. The problem still persists.

Comment: Then do editing  your question so it provides the complete code which shows the problem. Else no help is possible. As you see, my complete code does not have that problem. As said in my comment, maybe multiple threads are involved?

Comment: Thank you Axel, but it is really hard for me to put my code here because it involves more than 10 classes. Any suggestion on how can I share to make you understand my problem better?

Comment: I tried more and I now observe that it is the for loop which is causing the problem. Same code if I try to print QValues HashMap, commenting out the for loop, all results are fine. However when I use the for loop the result of HashMap as well as key and value separate values get changed. Any suggestion?

Comment: As said try determining if and, if so, how multi-threading is involved here. See my supplements. As I don't know what `bb` and `MSQATVHM` is exactly and even whether my suspicion is correct, I cannot suggest a solution. You needs to determine first whether my suspicion is correct.

Comment: @Spyyder: Btw.: Have you never heard something about `Java` naming conventions? Variable names never should be `Qvalues` and `IntegerSet` but `qValues` and `integerSet` instead. And a external library which uses `MSQATVHM` as a methode name would not be something I would trust of.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will try to find out the mentioned and get back. Anyway, I am going to try exporting my data in CSV format. I am guessing that won't cause the mentioned problem. I will get back to you once I have something.

Regarding your naming convention comment, I am new to the programming field and doing my best under the pressure I have. I am least bothered about naming at the moment but yes, I will take better care from now. The method MSQATVHM is created by me and not the library. This is done to match the file name for my reference.

Again, thank you for all your insights.